# Upload a picture to oData web service

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient, image-uploading, put

In my oData webservice I have a business object called `Ware`. This `Ware` has a property of type `Image` called `Picture`. When I want to get the picture in an UWP application using `HttpClient` I just call `http://localhost:8797/Data/Ware(2)/Picture`. The code is as follows:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(DataServiceAddress + "Data/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        using (HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var content = (StreamContent)message.Content;
            return await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
    }
```

This is working as expected and return me the picture as byte of array. 
Now I want to upload new `Picture` by doing a 'PUT'. I've tried the code bellow:

```
    public static async Task PutImage(string url, byte[] image)
    {
         var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
         using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
         {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(DataServiceAddress + "Data/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
            {
                using (var message = await client.PutAsync(url, httpContent))
                {
                    message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then when I'm calling `PutImage("Ware(2)/Picture", myFile.toByteArray())`, I'm getting `Bad Request` response. 
Interesting thing is that when I try `PUT` with *Postman* it's working fine. As you can see in the following picture I got *204* result and my picture has changed successfully.

[Screenshot: Postman is successful sending the file with a 'PUT' verb to the odata server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3cDh.png)

Can anyone please help me with that?

This is the generated code by Postman:

```
    PUT /Data/Ware(2)/Picture HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8797
    Authorization: Basic QWRtaW46
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Postman-Token: 37827f09-8841-7ccb-c462-d488ef4c4e9d

    undefined
```

I did a lot of googling. But there is no hope. :(

Comment: Did you test with Fiddler to see the generated code from your UWP app? Maybe there are some differeces here from your UWP code which caused the problem. By the way, your Httpclient API is from which namespace, system.web or windows.web?

Comment: Thank you Barry. It is  `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. I didn't know Fiddler. I will download it and let you now.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Really thank you. That app (Fiddler) helped me a lot. I fixed the problem. I'll post it as an answer. But now I have another problem. What can I do to set 'Picture' to null. (Remove Picture)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally It's done :)

```
   public static async Task PutImage(string url, byte[] image)
   {
        var httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(image);

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(DataServiceAddress + "Data/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url) { Content = httpContent })
            {

                httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
                using (var message = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working fine.